# Installing gcc4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, g++

I tried the following but I get the errors at the end. In order to make sure that 4.8.2 was not interfering, I removed it.

Any suggestions would be great!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-4.9 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
           Depends: gcc-4.9 (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++-4.9-dev (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
idf@C55t-A:/etc/apt$
```

**Edit 1**

When I used aptitude, I get these warnings although it seems to work

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did `sudo apt-get update` return any errors?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the last link above from Elder Geek. Thanks. See Edit 1 in original post for some weirdness though.